# Is it OK to answer old questions?

Tags: support

Because I'm quite new in this group, I'm reading archives and sometimes find interesting questions. Some of them already have answers, some -- also accepted answers. But I feel I can answer in another way, but I'm not sure if it is ok to say anything half a year or more for such a question.

Comment: It's certainly ok, but you should avoid repeating what has already been said. And if whatever new you have to add is very minor, perhaps it would be better if you posted it as a comment instead.

Comment: No, I don't want to repeat anything as it is useless, but for example add a new source etc. I mean the answer is (technically) correct, but its only problem that this is quite old.

Comment: Adding a new source would be an excellent reason to post a new answer. Unless it's just a link to a new source, in which case please consider posting it as a comment instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend answering old questions, because it helps develop the body of knowledge for that question, and it helps you become more comfortable with the site. By answering old questions it creates another opportunity for the community to review the question, and answers, for errors, etc.

Personally, I like to use the favorite function to mark questions that I intend to answer at some point, because I never know when I'll have the time to sit down and devote the time I want to answering a question.

The caveat is of course that you have to have something new to add to the question.

Comment: I accept your answer, because today I answered [a question](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/5851/2395) half a year after it had been asked, and later there was a nice answer by [John Craven](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/9154/2395), after I "brought" the question to life :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have something useful to add to the answer domain of an old question, please do so.

If you do it well, there's even a special badge for you: [Necromancer](https://history.stackexchange.com/badges/17/necromancer)